# Matrix inverse and Change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have 2 Change of Basis Matrices $ S_{A,B} $  and $ S_{A,C}$

I want determinate $ S_{C,B} $

We know that

$$ S_{A,B} S_{B,C} = S_{A,C} $$
$$ S_{B,C} = S_{A,B}^{-1} S_{A,C} $$

Now i'm quite not sure if 
$$ S_{C,B} = S_{B,C}^{-1} = S_{A,B} * S_{A,C}^{-1} \space\space (1) $$

or

$$ S_{C,B} = S_{B,C}^{-1} = S_{A,C}^{-1} *S_{A,B} \space\space (2) $$

if it's (2) why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if $A$ and $B$ are invertible, then $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$. So which of (1) and (2) fits that pattern?

Comment: @IsaakWahb No, the right equation is not $(2)$. Define vector spaces $V_A,V_B$ and $V_C$ with bases $A,B$ and $C$ respectively. Then we can denote $$\mathrm{id}^C_B: V_C \to V_B .$$ Note that this is the composition $$\mathrm{id}^A_B \circ {\mathrm{id}^A_C}^{-1}: V_C \to V_B.$$ Namely, $$\mathrm{id}^A_B: V_A \to V_B \quad \text{ after }\quad  {\mathrm{id}^A_C}^{-1}: V_C \to V_A .$$ So equation $(1)$ is correct.

Comment: @rogerl do you agree with Musse Redi ?

Comment: @MusséRedi The exercise's solution says it's (2) and i solved it as (1) so i'm confused now! shall i fellow the solution or you/myself

Comment: @IsaakWahb Let's use the answer. Firstly, assume $$[\mathrm{id}]^B_C =  {[\mathrm{id}]^A_C} \cdot {[\mathrm{id}]^A_B}^{-1}.$$ Secondly define matrices $A$ and $B$ by $$A = {[\mathrm{id}]^A_C} \quad \text{ and } \quad B = {[\mathrm{id}]^A_B}^{-1} .$$ Since $[\mathrm{id}]^C_B = {[\mathrm{id}]^B_C}^{-1}$, we have $$[\mathrm{id}]^C_B = B^{-1}A^{-1} = [\mathrm{id}]^A_B \cdot {[\mathrm{id}]^A_C}^{-1} .$$

Comment: @IsaakWahb When we take the inverse of a composition we also invert the order of operation. This is not accounted for in equation $(2)$ and that is the reason why it is incorrect.

Comment: It's (1), as @IsaakWahb points out. Look at the very first equation in your post. It says (renaming variables) that $[\mathrm{id}]_Y^X = [\mathrm{id}]_Y^Z[\mathrm{id}]_Z^X$. Now let $Y=C$, $X=B$, $Z=A$.

Comment: @MusséRedi you messed up my post with your edit, that's why we are now confused! You switched the matrices in my original post i had the following equations

$$ S_{A,B} S_{B,C} = S_{A,C} $$
$$ S_{B,C} = S_{A,B}^{-1} S_{A,C} $$

so as rogerl mentioned in his post the write answer should be

$$ S_{C,B} = S_{B,C}^{-1} = S_{A,C}^{-1} *S_{A,B} \space\space (2) $$

Comment: @rogerl thank you again, your answer was short and clear, was enough for me from the first moment.

Comment: @IsaakWahb I hereby apologize for wasting your time. In the future I'll mention the changes made in a big edit more carefully, if notational problems are concerned. I deemed the edit necessary because I found the notation $S_{A,B}$ ambiguous: are we going from $A$ to $B$ or the other way. Take for instance $$ S_{B,C} = S_{A,B}^{-1} S_{A,C}.$$ Since $S_{A,C}$ is applied before $S_{A,B}^{-1}$ it is clear that by $S_{B,C}$ we mean the basis transformation from $C$ to $B$. I could not notice this at first by looking at $S_{B,C}$, which is why I found it ambiguous.

Comment: @MusséRedi it's OK, I also find it ambiguous, but it's german way!